# Dynamic iframe height for Google Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to know if it is possible to have a dynamic height (100%) of a Google Form iframe?

Especially, when your Google form extends to two or more pages.. is there a way to have it resize to 100% height instead of putting in heigh pixel?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to embed a Google Forms iframe is to simply have a parent element that is 100vh. This way the iframe can measure it's required space vertically

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">
// Your embed code here with height and width set to 100%
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

100% means that it will fill 100% of the height of it's parent element, if there isn't a higher parent element, it will be 100% of the height of the `body`

```
iframe {
 height:100%;
}
```

Although, I'm sure your question will turn out to be not as simple as first indicated

Comment: Only if the parent is position: relative;

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for you to get the height of the iframe because browser security measures prevent javascript from accessing frame contents.

The only way that you would be able to do this is if you own both the page that will be included in an iframe, AND the page the iframe will live on. If you DO own both pages, you can use David Bradshaw's iframe resizer plugin. See https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer